# Nested quotes with poetry

Tags: context

I'm using context and trying to get nested quotes right. Here is a document that illustrates my problems:

```
\starttext
{\bf Closing quotes on new line.}
\startblockquote
The start of a really long quote. \startquote Some one is speaking
\startquote the speaker is quoting someone who is quoting some poetry:
\setuplines[before={\startnarrower},after={\stopnarrower}]\startlines
\startquote A line of poetry
another line of poetry
more lines of poetry

A line of poetry
another line of poetry
more lines of poetry\stopquote%
\stoplines%
\stopquote\stopquote
\stopblockquote
\hairline
{\bf Last line not indented correctly}
\startblockquote
The start of a really long quote. \startquote Some one is speaking
\startquote the speaker is quoteing someone who is quoting some poetry:
\setuplines[before={},after={}]\startlines
\leftskip=1in
\startquote A line of poetry
another line of poetry
more lines of poetry

A line of poetry
another line of poetry
more lines of poetry\stopquote%
\stoplines%
\stopquote\stopquote
\stopblockquote
\hairline
{\bf Quote marks repeat each line not each verse/paragraph}
\startblockquote
\setupdelimitedtext[quote][repeat=yes,middle={\symbol[leftquotation]}]
The start of a really long quote. \startquote Some one is speaking
\startquote the speaker is quoteing someone who is quoting some poetry:
\startlines
\leftskip=1in
\startquote A line of poetry
another line of poetry
more lines of poetry

A line of poetry
another line of poetry
more lines of poetry\stopquote%
\stoplines%
\stopquote\stopquote
\stopblockquote

more text
\stoptext
```

[image]

How can I block indent the Poetry (first two examples), but still get the quotes to close correctly?

How can I have the open quote repeat per verse/paragraph not per line?

Comment: I don't see an easy solution. It may be a good idea to ask this on the context mailing list